# Secret Manager Integration with EKS

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-secrets-manager

```html
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: profile-deployment
  namespace: tsc-sandbox-deployments
  labels:
    app: smoothie
    svc: profile
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: smoothie
      svc: profile
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: smoothie
        svc: profile
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: profile-sa
      volumes:
      - name: secrets-store-inline
        csi:
          driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
          readOnly: true
          volumeAttributes:
            secretProviderClass: profile-secrets-sandbox
      containers:
      - name: profile
        image: ${ECRREGISTRY}/profile:${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
        - name: spring.profiles.active
          value: ${ENVPROFILE}
        - name: app.olo.url
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: STAGE_TSC_APP_OLO_URL
              name: profile-sandbox-secrets
        
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8097
        volumeMounts:
        - name: secrets-store-inline
          mountPath: "/mnt/secrets-store"
          readOnly: true
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
          requests:
            cpu: 500m
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /profile/actuator/health/readiness
            port: 8097
          initialDelaySeconds: 100
          periodSeconds: 5
          successThreshold: 1
          failureThreshold: 3
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "sleep 90"]
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  strategy:
      type: RollingUpdate
      rollingUpdate:
        maxSurge: 1
        maxUnavailable: 1
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: profile-svc
  namespace: tsc-sandbox-deployments
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /profile/actuator/health/readiness
spec:
  selector:
    app: smoothie
    svc: profile
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8097

---
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: profile-secrets-sandbox
  namespace: tsc-sandbox-deployments
spec:
  provider: aws
  parameters:    
    objects: |
      - objectName: "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        objectAlias: "profileSandbox"
        objectType: "secretsmanager"
        jmesPath:
          - path: APP_OLO_URL
            objectAlias: TSC_APP_OLO_URL
  secretObjects:
    - secretName: profile-sandbox-secrets
      type: Opaque
      type: Opaque
      data:
        - key: STAGE_TSC_APP_OLO_URL
          objectName: TSC_APP_OLO_URL
```

I am trying to integrate AWS secret manager with EKS..
When I am building my deployment.yaml I am getting below error.

Events:
Type     Reason       Age                From               Message

---

Normal   Scheduled    43s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned tsc-sandbox-deployments/profile-deployment-6d7c7c75f-dvxdf to ip-xxxxxxx.us-east-2.compute.internal
**Warning  FailedMount  10s (x7 over 43s)  kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "secrets-store-inline" : r**pc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to mount secrets store objects for pod tsc-sandbox-deployments/profile-deployment-6d7c7c75f-dvxdf, err: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = **Failed to fetch secret from all regions: profileSandbox**

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

I have already installed csi-driver and AWS provider.

Comment: Can you paste a copy of your manifest here? Hard to tell what is happening from your description. It is likely a configuration issue.

Comment: added the manifest file here